# How can I calculate custom made business hours between two date columns for an entire dataframe? (output as a new column so I can chart it)

Tags: python, dataframe

Consider:

```
from business_duration import businessDuration

import holidays as pyholidays

start_date = df['assigned_at']

end_date = df['completion_date']

biz_open_time=time(9,0,0)

biz_close_time=time(16,0,0)

US_holiday_list = pyholidays.US(state='CA')

unit_hour='hour'
```

When I try applying this code to my data frame, I get this error:

`df['business_sla'] = businessDuration(startdate=start_date, enddate=end_date, starttime=biz_open_time, endtime=biz_close_time, holidaylist=US_holiday_list, unit=unit_hour)`

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent
call last)
<ipython-input-22-4c73e233f159> in <module>
----> 1 df['business_sla'] =
businessDuration(startdate=start_date, enddate=end_date,
starttime=biz_open_time, endtime=biz_close_time,
holidaylist=US_holiday_list, unit=unit_hour)


ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use
a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Is it not possible to iterate over my entire data frame?

I am trying to count the business hours for tasks to see how long it takes a user to complete it. I only want to count business hours, and some analysts work Saturdays as their business day, and some alternate Sundays (e.g., Tuesday through Saturday).

**If Jason, in this example, works Saturdays, all cases on Saturday need to be counted 9-5 pm for him. *Also* if John and James alternate Sundays, then all cases assigned to them on their Sundays need to be counted only 9-5 for tasks placed in their name**

Essentially, every day of the week needs to count 9-5 pm for the business hours tracking, just looking to exclude Saturdays for some, and exclude Sundays for others while counting all other days.

My data frame looks like this now:

| product type | analyst_name | assigned_at | completed_at | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| product A | john | 2021-09-13 | 2021-09-13 | 0 Days 00:38:00 |
| product B | james | 2021-09-13 | 2021-09-13 | 0 Days 00:59:00 |
| product A | jason | 2021-09-13 | 2021-09-13 | 0 Days 01:01:00 |
| product A | john | 2021-09-10 | 2021-09-13 | 3 Days 00:45:00 |
| product B | james | 2021-09-10 | 2021-09-13 | 3 Days 01:16:00 |
| product A | jason | 2021-09-10 | 2021-09-13 | 3 Days 01:30:0 |

Cases assigned on Friday are counting the entire time the task was live until Monday it was finished.

Example:

If they were assigned at 4 pm on Friday, I want to count only one hour Friday, and then the time Monday morning at 9 am until completion.

The new data frame would look more like this (assuming that all analysts didn't do their deals assigned on Friday at 4 pm. I'm adding one hour to their SLA + their time to work them on Monday morning):

| product type | analyst_name | assigned_at | completed_at | duration | business_hours_sla |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| product A | john | 2021-09-13 | 2021-09-13 | 0 Days 00:38:00 | 0 Days 00:38:00 |
| product B | james | 2021-09-13 | 2021-09-13 | 0 Days 00:59:00 | 0 Days 00:59:00 |
| product A | jason | 2021-09-13 | 2021-09-13 | 0 Days 01:01:00 | 0 Days 01:01:00 |
| product A | john | 2021-09-10 | 2021-09-13 | 3 Days 00:45:00 | 0 Days 01:45:00 |
| product B | james | 2021-09-10 | 2021-09-13 | 3 Days 01:16:00 | 0 Days 02:16:00 |
| product A | jason | 2021-09-10 | 2021-09-13 | 3 Days 01:30:0 | 0 Days 02:30:0 |

The third-party package: *[Business_Duration](https://pypi.org/project/business-duration/)*

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412049).

Comment: I think the example 3 on the [GitHub repository's readme](https://github.com/gnaneshwar441/Business_Duration) of the package you seem to be using should help you do what you want. **Note**: If you use some 3rd party package people might not be familiar with say it in your question and provide links to it, for all we know it could have been some module of your own and we would be left wondering what those functions do.

Comment: thats fair i can go get the link for the package . thank you. I have tried modeling example 3 and cant seem to get it to work, my best attempt so far is im gonna have to make a table with every hour of the calendar year and pair it to see whether or not its a business hour. @AbdulAzizBarkat